# Zokrates code not compiling in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, web3.py, zero-knowledge, zokrates

I am trying to work on Zokrates in Remix IDE

I am trying this code :

```
import "hashes/sha3/512bit" as sha256packed

def main(private field value, private field before, field valueHash, field beforeHash, field afterHash) -> (field):
    priBefore = sha256packed([0, 0, 0, before])
    priAfter = sha256packed([0, 0, 0, before-value])
    field result = if(\
        value <= before &&\
        priBefore[0] == beforeHash &&\
        priAfter[0] == afterHash \
    ) then 1 else 0 fi
    return result
```

The code is from AwesomeHuang's [Github repository](https://github.com/AwesomeHuang/Zokrates_Demo)

However, i am getting the following error in the Zokrates compiler :

[image: Error Message in REMIX IDE]

Can anyone help me resolve this error ?

I am new to Zero Knowledge Proofs and to Zokrates itself, hence i am quite confused

I would be grateful for the help !

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but you need to add the type when declaring a new variable with the current syntax.

```
field[2] priBefore = sha256packed([0,0,0,before]);
```